# How to create a conditional statement that is based on the preceding function that ran

Tags: python

I have output from different functions that will need to be parsed with slight differences, but don't think the best option is to create multiple functions for each type of output.

I've reviewed many sites regarding Python 3 conditional statements, but have not seen a way to create a conditional statement that is T or F based on the function that called it.

```
def function1():
    some code
    general_function(resultOfSomeCode)

def function2():
    some code
    general_function(resultOfSomeCode)

def general_function(resultOfSomeCode):
    if general_function was called by function1:
        do this
    elif general_function was called by function2:
        do this
```

I'm not sure if this is possible, or if there is a best practices way to do this.  I can always call multiple functions dependent on the number of ways I need to parse the output, but being newer to programming wanted to see how this should be handled. Suggestions or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

```
def function1():
    some code
    general_function(resultOfSomeCode, function1.__name__)

def function2():
    some code
    general_function(resultOfSomeCode, function2.__name__)

def general_function(resultOfSomeCode, calling_func_name):
    if calling_func_name__ == 'function1':
        do this
    elif calling_func_name__ == 'function2':
        do this
```

Though it will be much cleaner to pass an argument that defines the behaviour you want in `general_func` instead of the calling function itself.

Comment: Excellent, and thank you @rdas.  I think I'll use your cleaner idea and just pass an additional argument with the output to ```general_func``` defining which conditional path should be taken.